# Why the size of MySQL MyISAM table is the same after striping some data from VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql, varchar, myisam, size-reduction

I need to reduce the size of MySQL database. I recoded some information which striped ';' and ':' from `sources` column (~10% char reduction). After doing so, the size of the table is exactly the same as before. How is it possible? I'm using MyISAM engine.

btw: Unfortunately, I cannot compress the tables with `myisampack`.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test SELECT protid1, protid2, CS, REPLACE(REPLACE(sources, ':', ''), ';', '') FROM homologs_9606; 
Query OK, 41917131 rows affected (4 min 11.30 sec)
Records: 41917131  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select TABLE_NAME name, ROUND(TABLE_ROWS/1e6, 3) 'million rows', ROUND(DATA_LENGTH/power(2,30), 3) 'data GB', ROUND(INDEX_LENGTH/power(2,30), 3) 'index GB' from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('homologs_9606', 'test') ORDER BY TABLE_ROWS DESC LIMIT 10;
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------+
| name          | million rows | data GB | index GB |
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------+
| test          |       41.917 |   0.857 |    1.075 |
| homologs_9606 |       41.917 |   0.887 |    1.075 |
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from homologs_9606 limit 10;
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------+
| protid1 | protid2 | CS    | sources                        |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------+
| 5635338 | 1028608 | 0.000 | 10:,1                          |
| 5644385 | 1028611 | 0.947 | 5:1,1;8:0.943,35;10:1,1;11:1,1 |
| 5652325 | 1028611 | 0.947 | 5:1,1;8:0.943,35;10:1,1;11:1,1 |
| 5641128 | 1028612 | 1.000 | 8:1,10                         |
| 5636414 | 1028616 | 0.038 | 8:0.038,104;10:,1              |
| 5636557 | 1028616 | 0.000 | 8:,4                           |
| 5637419 | 1028616 | 0.011 | 5:,1;8:0.011,91;10:,1          |
| 5641196 | 1028616 | 0.080 | 5:1,1;8:0.074,94;10:,1;11:,4   |
| 5642914 | 1028616 | 0.000 | 8:,3                           |
| 5643778 | 1028616 | 0.056 | 8:0.057,70;10:,1               |
+---------+---------+-------+--------------------------------+
10 rows in set (4.55 sec)

mysql> select * from test limit 10;
+---------+---------+-------+-------------------------+
| protid1 | protid2 | CS    | sources                 |
+---------+---------+-------+-------------------------+
| 5635338 | 1028608 | 0.000 | 10,1                    |
| 5644385 | 1028611 | 0.947 | 51,180.943,35101,1111,1 |
| 5652325 | 1028611 | 0.947 | 51,180.943,35101,1111,1 |
| 5641128 | 1028612 | 1.000 | 81,10                   |
| 5636414 | 1028616 | 0.038 | 80.038,10410,1          |
| 5636557 | 1028616 | 0.000 | 8,4                     |
| 5637419 | 1028616 | 0.011 | 5,180.011,9110,1        |
| 5641196 | 1028616 | 0.080 | 51,180.074,9410,111,4   |
| 5642914 | 1028616 | 0.000 | 8,3                     |
| 5643778 | 1028616 | 0.056 | 80.057,7010,1           |
+---------+---------+-------+-------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe test;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| protid1 | int(10) unsigned | YES  | PRI | NULL    |       |
| protid2 | int(10) unsigned | YES  | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CS      | float(4,3)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sources | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe homologs_9606;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| protid1 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| protid2 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| CS      | float(4,3)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sources | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT1: Added average column length.**

```
mysql> select AVG(LENGTH(sources)) from test; 
+----------------------+
| AVG(LENGTH(sources)) |
+----------------------+
|               5.2177 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (10.04 sec)

mysql> select AVG(LENGTH(sources)) from homologs_9606; 
+----------------------+
| AVG(LENGTH(sources)) |
+----------------------+
|               6.8792 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (9.95 sec)
```

**EDIT2: I was able to strip some more MB by setting `NOT NULL` to all columns.**

```
mysql> drop table test
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)

mysql> CREATE table test (protid1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', protid2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', CS FLOAT(4,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', sources VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (protid1, protid2), KEY `idx_protid2` (protid2)) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=ascii;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test SELECT protid1, protid2, CS, REPLACE(REPLACE(sources, ':', ''), ';', '') FROM homologs_9606; 
Query OK, 41917131 rows affected (2 min 7.84 sec)

mysql> select TABLE_NAME name, ROUND(TABLE_ROWS/1e6, 3) 'million rows', ROUND(DATA_LENGTH/power(2,30), 3) 'data GB', ROUND(INDEX_LENGTH/power(2,30), 3) 'index GB' from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('homologs_9606', 'test');
Records: 41917131  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

+---------------+--------------+---------+----------+
| name          | million rows | data GB | index GB |
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------+
| homologs_9606 |       41.917 |   0.887 |    1.075 |
| test          |       41.917 |   0.842 |    1.075 |
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Have you run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`  ?

Comment: yes, the size is the same.

Comment: Can you include AVG(LENGTH(sources)) for both tables? And also the character set for each table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` is better than `DESCRIBE tablename`)

Comment: This is a great question, by the way. You clearly stated your observations, your storage engine and some relevant queries. It shows that you have put thought into the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I've learned quite a few useful things :) So, setting NOT NULL strips a few more megabytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not exactly the same. Your query clearly shows that `test` is about 30 MB smaller than `homologs_9606`:

```
+---------------+--------------+---------+
| name          | million rows | data GB |
+---------------+--------------+---------+
| test          |       41.917 |   0.857 | <-- 0.857 < 0.887
| homologs_9606 |       41.917 |   0.887 |
+---------------+--------------+---------+
```

How much storage should we expect for your table? Let us check [Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html):

```
INTEGER(10): 4 bytes
FLOAT(4): 4 bytes
VARCHAR(100): L+1
```

where L is the number of character bytes, which is usually one byte per character but sometimes more if you use a Unicode character set.

Your rows on average will need:

```
INTEGER + INTEGER + FLOAT + VARCHAR =
4 + 4 + 4 + (L + 1) = L + 13 bytes
```

We can infer your original average L as `(0.887*1024^3 / 41917131) - 13 = 9.72`. You say that you stripped 10% from `sources`, which means your new L is `9.72*0.9 = 8.75`. That gives an expected new total storage requirement of `((8.75 + 13) * 41917131) / 1024^3 = 0.849 GB`

I suspect that the difference (between 0.849 and 0.857) might be due to the fact that `test` have two columns set as NULLable that `homologs_9606` do not have, but I [do not know enough](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/record-contents.html) about the MyISAM engine to calculate this exactly. I can however guess! On a minimum you would need 1 bit per column per row to store a `NULL` state, which in your case means two bits per row or `2*41917131 = 83834262 bits = 10 479 283 bytes = 0.010 GB`. The total `0.849+0.010 = 0.859` shoots slightly over the goal (about 2 MB too much). But I have made some roundings and your 10% figure is also an estimate so I am sure the rest is lost in translation.

Another reason could be if you use a Unicode character set on `sources` in `test`, in which case some characters may use more than one byte each, but since the NULLable columns seems to account for everything I do not think this is the case for your table.

## Summary

- Your two tables are not the same size, they differ by 30 MB.
- The size of your new table is around the expected size.
- You can save some more space in your new table by making `protid1` and `protid2` into `NOT NULL` columns.

Comment: Thanks for very thoughtful answer, Emil! I'll set NOT NULL values.

Comment: I know very little about your data, but you might want to consider setting the integer columns to MEDIUMINT *if* you will not need the extra range (see [Integer Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) for exact range). That would save about 40 MB per column.

Comment: Good hint. I was trying it before, but the protid1/2 may exceed max MEDIUMINT in the near future. Anyway, using MEDIUMINT frees another 19Mb (0.823GB)

Answer (score 0):

The "table" is stored in a `.MYD` file.  This file will *never* shrink due to `UPDATEs` or `DELETEs`.  `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (or the equivalent query into `information_schema`) may show `Data_length` shrinking, but `Data_free` will increase.

You can shrink the `.MYD` file by doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  But that will copy the table over, thereby needing extra disk space during the process.  And this action is only very rarely worth doing.

Changing to `NOT NULL` may not free up space if you had a lot of nulls -- "" takes 1 or 2 bytes for a `VARCHAR` because of the length.  (And your code may need to handle '' differently than `NULL`.)

The space taken for each row is actually 1 byte more than previously mentioned -- this byte handles knowing whether the row exists or is the beginning of a hole.

For large text fields, I like to do this to save space.  (This applies to both MyISAM and InnoDB.)  Compress the text and store it into a `BLOB` column (instead of `TEXT`).  For most text, that is a 3:1 shrinkage.  It takes a little extra code and CPU time in the client, but it saves a lot of I/O in the server.  Often the net result is "faster".  I would not use it for the varchar you have; I would only do it on columns bigger than, say, 50 characters average.

Back to the original question.  It sounds like there were only about 30M colons and semicolons in the entire table.  Could it be that the first 10 rows are not representative?

Comment: If you read the schema included in the question you will see that the original table had only NOT NULL fields so changing them to NOT NULL in the new table is possible without losing any data.